# Why is it returning all creeps instead of just the ones with the role "upgrader"?

Tags: javascript, screeps

```
        let foundUpgraderCreeps = spawner.room.find(FIND_MY_CREEPS,
        { fitler: (creep) => { return creep.memory.role === 'upgrader'; }});
```

For whatever reason this here is returning all the creeps in the room, I have a creep with the role and all the other ones work fine, but Upgrader creeps doesnt, please help.

Edit: 'spawner' is a reference to the spawner in the room.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe its because you have "fitler" instead of "filter" at the beginning of the second line.